# Как вывести список кортежей (координат)?

Tags: python, ооп, классы

> Напишите программу, в которой пользователь вводит координаты x, y с клавиатуры, создается соответствующий экземпляр и он сохраняется в списке. Количество вводимых объектов N=5. Затем, вывести их атрибуты в консоль.

Вопрос, как вывести список кортежей (координат), можно ли без цикла это сделать, как вывод обычного списка. У меня получается что выводятся просто объекты без значений print(s) - <**main**.Point object at 0x000002AF6273AFA0>...

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x,self.y = x,y

    def getCoords(self):
        return self.x, self.y

n = int(input("Введите кол-во экземпляров."))
s = []
for i in range(n):
    x = list(map(int,input('Введите координаты точки: \n').split()))
    point = Point(x[0],x[1])
    s.append(point)

for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[i].getCoords())
```

Comment: этот код все правильно выводит

Comment: да, но он выводит кортежи на новой строке, а хотелось бы так [(),(),()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для того, чтобы можно было вывести список объектов в удобоворимой форме, необходимо у класса `Point` определить метод `__repr__` или `__str__`

подробней о них можно прочитать тут  [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

Comment: добавил их    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.x},{self.y}"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.x, self.y      уже выводятся значения, но хотелось бы получить такой формат [(),(),()],  а у меня другой (ниже приведен), как сделать?  вывод [1,2, 3,4]

Comment: вот ссылка https://prnt.sc/1urakpb

Comment: так поставь скобки внутри `__repr__` /`__str__`   `return  f"({self.x}, {self.y})"` и можешь просто `print(s)`

Comment: да, сработало, отлично. спасибо. print(s) то что нужно)) надо будет с ними попрактиковаться почаще, очень неплохая тема)

Answer (score 2):

вместо:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[i].getCoords())
```

попробуйте:

```
print([i.getCoords() for i in s])
```

ввод-вывод:

```
Введите кол-во экземпляров.2
Введите координаты точки: 
5 10
Введите координаты точки: 
6 15
[(5, 10), (6, 15)]
```

Comment: вот оно, то что надо, про генератор то я и забыл совсем. Спасибо!